# A hybrid of cache based and query based paging in hibernate/JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, memcached, hazelcast

If the result set is large, then having the entire result set **in memory (server cache e.g. hazelcast)** will not be feasible. With large result sets, you cannot afford to have them in memory. In such case, you have to fetch a chunk of data at a time (query based paging). The down side of using query based paging, is that there will be multiple calls to the database for multiple page requests.

Can anyone suggest how to implement a hybrid approach of it.
I haven't put any sample code here since I think the question is more about a logic instead of specific code. Still if you need sample code I can put it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The most effective solution is to use the primary key as a paging criterion.This enables us to rely of first class constructs like a between range query which is simple for the RDBMS to optimize, the primary key of the queried entity will most likely be indexed already.

Retrieving data using a range query on the primary key is a two-step process. First one have to retrieve the collection of primary-keys, followed by a step to generate the intervals to properly identify a proper subset of the data,followed by the actual queries against the data.

This approach is almost as fast as the brute-force version. The memory consumption is about one tenth. By selecting the appropriate page-size for this implementation, you may alter the ratio between execution time and memory consumption. This version is also stateless, it does not keep references to resources like the `ScrollableResults` version does, nor does it strain the database like the version using `setFirstResult/setMaxResult`.

[Effective pagination using Hibernate](http://devperspective.blogspot.com.by/2007/03/effective-pagination-using-hibernate.html)

Comment: The requirement here is to use hybrid approach of in-memory cache(we use hazelcast) and hibernate paging.